# Android Studio design-preview can't display a a specific size-combination

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

So this is an Android Studio problem. The example will run on the device, but won't be shown if I try to view the design-preview for my activity in Android Studio.
I created a round_button.xml and use it for a button in activity_layout.xml

The preview is shown as long as the button doesn't have the same width as height. If that is the case, the preview-window won't even show the device, but just the grey background.
If i change the height of the button to 49dp or 51dp everything works fine.

As I said, the app is still runnable and will show my perfectly round button on the device, but the Android Studio preview funnily doesn't.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and is there a way to fix it?

round_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/light_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:onClick="doThings"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should probably ask a question.. like "is there a work around?" "is there an error in my code?" "is this a known bug?" etc.

Comment: Makes sense. Added a question :)